# Ошибка при тестировании

Tags: java, java-stream

При выполнении этой части кода:

```
final String testCases = MethodSourceParametrizedTesting.testCases()
                .map(arg -> Arrays.stream(arg.get()).map(Object::toString).collect(joining(",")))
                .collect(joining(";"));
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method map((arg)->Arr[...]",")))
  location: interface java.lang.String[][]
```

Сам тест:

```
class MethodSourceParametrizedTesting {

    Factorial factorial = new Factorial();

    public static String[][] testCases() {
        return new String[][]{
                {"1","1"}, {"2", "2"}, {"5", "120"}};
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testCases")
    void testFactorial(String in, String expected) {
        assertEquals(expected, factorial.factorial(in));
    }

}
```

Comment: добавил описание ошибок и пояснения в ответ

Comment: все получилось?)

Comment: Да, получилось, благодарю!

Comment: ну слава богу) удачи вам)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ошибка №1

> java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   method map((arg)->Arr[...]",")))
> location: interface java.lang.String[][]

Он ругается на то, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `map` сразу на результате `testCases()`
Результатом вызова которого является двумерный массив и он такого метода не имеет
Его нужно обернуть `Arrays.stream()` и потом уже вызывать `map()`

```
Arrays
    .stream(MethodSourceParametrizedTesting.testCases())
    .map( /** ... */);
```

#### Ошибка №2

```
map(arg -> Arrays.stream(arg.get()) // ...
```

В данном случае лямбда получает на вход `String[]`
И опять же, массив не имеет метода `get()`
Тут мы просто убираем `get()` и передаем `arg` в `stream()` как есть

```
stream(arg)
```

#### Рабочий пример

```
final String testCases = Arrays.stream(MethodSourceParametrizedTesting.testCases())
                .map(arg -> Arrays.stream(arg).map(Object::toString).collect(joining(",")))
                .collect(joining(";"));
System.out.println(testCases);
```

out

```
1,1;2,2;5,120
```

## UPDATE

### возвращаем сразу Stream+Supplier

Так как мы не можем изменить

```
final String testCases = MethodSourceParametrizedTesting.testCases()
                .map(arg -> Arrays.stream(arg.get()).map(Object::toString).collect(joining(",")))
                .collect(joining(";"));
```

То нам нужно подстроиться так, чтобы у нас не возникало никаких ошибок.

1. для того чтобы при вызове `testCases().map(/**...*/)` не возникала ошибка нам следует не обернуть вызов `testCases()` в `Arrays.stream(/**...*/)`, а сразу возвращать Stream из `testCases()`... тогда map будет работать нормально
2. второй нашей проблемой был вызов `arg.get()`
   мы там имели `String[]` на входе, но как известно `String[]`, не имеет метода `get()`...
    И подумав, что же они там могут ждать - я не придумал ничего лучше как функциональьный интерфейс `Supplier`, все что умеет который - это возвращать элементы с помощью метода `get()`

```
public static Stream<Supplier<String[]>> testCases() {
    return (Stream<Supplier<String[]>>)IntStream.range(1, 6).mapToObj((i)->{
        Integer current = i;
        Supplier<String[]> item  = () -> {
            Integer result = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= current ; j++) {
                result = result * j;
            }
            String[] pair = { Integer.toString(current), Integer.toString(result)};
            return pair;
        };
        return item;
        }
    );
}
```

Вывод:

```
1,1;2,2;3,6;4,24;5,120
```

Что соответствует факториалу

## UPDATE 2

> **Замечание:**
> Если честно, то я старый дед и работал с `Java` задолго до выхода `JDK 1.8` и появления `Stream`'ов
> Знаю я их потольку-поскольку и не могу сказать что они прям очень плотно засели в моем арсенале, поэтому если что-то можно было сделать эффективнее и элегантнее - не серчайте

когда начал писать объяснения, понял, что лучше упростить все до нЕльзя - и Вам понятнее будет, и проще, и практичнее.

я вернулся к старому варианту без итераторов, генераторов и прочего...чтобы все можно было статично задать и получить.

Собственно вся хитрость просто в том, что я

- взял заранее определенный двумерный массив
- сделал стрим на основе этого массива
- и смапил `Stream<String[]>` который в качестве элементов имеет массив строк, в `Stream<Supplier<String[]>>` стрим каждый из элементов которого может получить массив строк с помощью функционального интерфейса `Supplier<T>`

Для последнего нужно просто вызвать метод `map()` и передать туда лямбду, которая будет приводить массив строк `String[]` в лямбду `Supplier<String>`

Делаем мы это так:

```
// получаем на вход String[] pair
pair -> { 
    // Объявляем лямбду, единственной задачей которой, является возвращение pair
    Supplier<String[]> item  = () -> pair;
    // возвращаем не pair, а лямбду, которая уже сможет вернуть pair
    // запутанно? - да!
    // а что вы хотели? такое условие задания
    return item;
}
```

**И уже рабочий вариант метода:**

```
public static Stream<Supplier<String[]>> testCases() {
    String[][] cases = new String[][]{
            {"1","1"}, {"2", "2"}, {"5", "120"}
        };
    return Arrays.stream(cases).map(pair -> {
        Supplier<String[]> item  = () -> pair;
        return item;
    });
}
```

Вывод:

```
1,1;2,2;5,120
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138351/discussion-on-answer-by-----).